# NIO channels example for file transfer

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I want to write a simple NIO example for file transfer.

I want to have a nio server which will be able to transfer files from one machine to another over the network.

Can someone point me a good example or a starting point?

Until now I have a working program and I want to transfer an image

```
Image image = new Image(shell.getDisplay(), imageData);
```

from one machine to another.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have to use NIO?  The cost of compressing the Image, so it can be sent, is likely to make any performance advantage very small (but it increases the complexity) I would just write it the simplest way you can.

Comment: Actually I want to : 1) take a screenshot every x seconds of an android device from node 1 (usb connection), 2) view the screenshots as live video from node 2 (internet connection). Can you suggest me a proper solution?